# Rank based on row number SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, grouping, ranking, rownum

I want to group rank my table data by rowcount.  First 12 rows that are ordered by date for each ProductID would get value = 1.  Next 12 rows would get value = 2 assigned and so on.

How table structure looks:

```
For ProductID = 1267 are below associated dates:
02-01-2016 
03-01-2016
.
. (skipping months..table has one date per month)
.
12-01-2016
02-01-2017
.
.
.
02-01-2018
```

Comment: you might want more than 5 rows of sample data.... (if the smallest breakdown is 12 it needs to be a little > 12) just a thought, also what is the table name and the date column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number() over()` with some arithmetic to calculate groups of 12 ordered by date (per productid). Change the sort to ASCendng or DESCendng to suit your need.

> ```
> select *
> , (11 + row_number() over(partition by productid order by somedate DESC)) / 12 as rnk
> from mytable
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> myTableID | productid      | somedate            | rnk
> --------: | :------------- | :------------------ | :--
>         9 | 123456         | 2018-11-12 08:24:25 | 1  
>         8 | 123456         | 2018-10-02 12:29:04 | 1  
>         7 | 123456         | 2018-09-09 02:39:30 | 1  
>         2 | 123456         | 2018-09-02 08:49:37 | 1  
>         1 | 123456         | 2018-07-04 12:25:06 | 1  
>         5 | 123456         | 2018-06-06 11:38:50 | 1  
>        12 | 123456         | 2018-05-23 21:12:03 | 1  
>        18 | 123456         | 2018-04-02 03:59:16 | 1  
>         3 | 123456         | 2018-01-02 03:42:24 | 1  
>        17 | 123456         | 2017-11-29 03:19:32 | 1  
>        10 | 123456         | 2017-11-10 00:45:41 | 1  
>        13 | 123456         | 2017-11-05 09:53:38 | 1  
>        16 | 123456         | 2017-10-20 15:39:42 | 2  
>         4 | 123456         | 2017-10-14 19:25:30 | 2  
>        20 | 123456         | 2017-09-21 21:31:06 | 2  
>         6 | 123456         | 2017-04-06 22:10:58 | 2  
>        14 | 123456         | 2017-03-24 23:35:52 | 2  
>        19 | 123456         | 2017-01-22 05:07:23 | 2  
>        11 | 123456         | 2016-12-13 19:17:08 | 2  
>        15 | 123456         | 2016-12-02 03:22:32 | 2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=71a1b8d5a0d81288237a64abd62c1ea0)*